# randomly split DataFrame by group?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random, scikit-learn

I have a DataFrame where multiple rows share group_id values (very large number of groups).

Is there an elegant way to randomly split this data into training and test data in a way that the training and test sets do not share group_id?

The best process I can come up with right now is
 - create mask from msk = np.random.rand()
 - apply it to the DataFrame
 - check test file for rows that share group_id with training set and move these rows to training set.

This is clearly non-elegant and has multiple issues (including the possibility that the test data ends up empty). I feel like there must be a better way, is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there is an easy way !

- create a list / array of unique group_ids
- create a random mask for this list
- and use the mask to split the file